# Pandas from_csv is not importing part of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have CSV data of the form:

```
<date> <time>,<number>,<number>,<number>....
```

Eg:

```
2019-11-21 13:31:26.616,48.474701,27.400757,148.585745,173.858999,<more number columns>
```

I'm importing using:

```
pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Pandas is cutting off the date and hour part of that column. So the timestamp column of the resulting dataframe only contains the time, and is type object, not a datetime.

For example, `df['Timestamp']` gives:

```
0          13:16.3
1          13:17.3
2          13:18.3
3          13:19.3
4          13:20.3
            ...   
2205161    39:55.9
2205162    39:56.9
2205163    39:57.9
2205164    39:58.9
2205165    39:59.9
Name: Timestamp, Length: 2205166, dtype: object
```

How can I import that first column properly?

Edit: example data now available at:
https://github.com/AndrewMoscoe/PythonProblem/blob/master/2019-11-18.txt

Comment: Import it as string and parse it later with pandas. To_datetime

Comment: @Kingindanord tried ```pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')```

There is no difference in the resulting Timestamp column. It's still discarding the date and hour.

Comment: I can't recreate this problem - works just fine on my machine - are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: @HaydenEastwood 3.6.9

At this point I'm thinking it might be something to do with trying to load a file from an NTFS drive via python running in WSL

Comment: @Andrew your problem is not clear since we don't have your data. Try to save your csv as excel and then use pd.read_excel()

Comment: Are you sure there's no comma between the date and time? Given the column gets parsed as 'Timestamp' I'd naturally think the data are arrange to have a separate date and time column...

Comment: @Kingindanord https://github.com/AndrewMoscoe/PythonProblem/blob/master/2019-11-18.txt

That's not really feasible given the number of files and data size I need to work with, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in the command its self. I could import your data without problem.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I actually copy and past your data into a .txt file and then just rename it to .csv and it worked well. However, when I opened the .csv file again with excel, changed nothing and saved it. the import looks wrong now:

[image]

so make sure that your csv contains exactly what they should contain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing `keep_date_col =True`?
[read_csv docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Just tried that, there is no difference in the output.

Answer (score 0):

If the first step isn't working, you could always try stating the format explicitly and seeing if that works. Since I can't replicate your original mistake, I'm only guessing that the below could be a work around:

```
# NB: csv file = file.csv containing 1 line, 5 columns, as below:
# 2019-11-21 13:31:26.616,48.474701,27.400757,148.585745,173.858999

import pandas as pd
filename = 'file.csv'
#f = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', names=('date','2nd','3rd','4th','5th'))
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print (df)
```